# Is it IMPOSSIBLE to hide the address bar in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, window.open

I want to hide the new popup window's address bar. I gooogled a lot and all of the results were this.

> This is no longer possible in modern browsers due to security restrictions.
>
> Official(-ish) Sources:
>
> **Firefox**
>
> In Firefox 3, dom.disable_window_open_feature.location now defaults to true, forcing the presence of the Location Bar much like in IE7. See bug 337344 for more information.
>
> **Internet Explorer 7 and later**
>
> In Internet Explorer 6, location specifies whether to display the Address Bar.
>
> (Implying the behaviour ends with IE6)
>
> **Chrome/Chromium**
>
> Those toolbar hiding parameters are ignored in Chrome. You will also notice that modern browsers are moving towards not hiding it as security / anti phishing measures. Also see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=337344

Which means `window.open`'s location option no longer works.

Is it really impossible to hide the address bar? Any good solution? Our project really need to hide the address bar. The request parameter is sending session id, and my boss wants to hide it. It is calling the Get RESTAPI, so hiding the parameter with POST is not a choice.

Any good idea?

Comment: "I don't know why, but that is the requirement." Maybe it's time to find out why, because it's not possible.

Comment: Talk to whomever gave you the requirement.  They may not know it is impossible.  There may be a better way of doing what they want to accomplish.  Maybe they want to hide the request parameters from view and not the whole URL.

Comment: @Jeanne Boyarsky yes, the request parameter is the reason, it is sending the session id and my boss wants to hide it. the url is calling a RESTapi, so POST method is impossible. Is there a way to hide the reqeust parameters?

Comment: Well, it's not as if hiding the address bar (even if it was possible) would prevent someone from seeing the requested url through the dev console or other means. It's a fools errand.

Comment: @Canna REST supports POST although it is possible your API doesn't.  And POST is meant for write operations so it would be misusing it anyway.  You could use an iframe so the REST get is "hidden."  As steveax notes, a determined user can still see it, but it isn't staring people in the face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much answered yourself, that it's impossible for security reasons. But you can still use iframes and ajax.

Just imagine a scenario, when popup with a fake address bar opens, you visit some site with a fake internet transaction dialogue box and somebody steals your real money. Weird, but 7 years ago it was possible.